# Builld a Course Registration website with Drupal

Tags: events, drupal, drupal-7, registration

We want to launch an entrepreneurship training/mentorship outfit where we train people on how to set up small businesses and now I as a part of the academy team with web design knowledge (Drupal), I have been asked to develop the website.

I am trying to build the website but my team requires that attendants while trying to register for a course would create an account on the website filled with extended profile data(I will unlock the profile module for this), then they will apply for one out of a few numbered courses.

On their profile page, they would be able to view their courses as in courses they registered on the site previously. And they can register for additional courses if they want. On the course registration page, they would find a list of available courses and they click as they wish to register on the ones they want.

Please what are the required Drupal modules to achieve this functionality and any more tips that would help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need profile, have a look at the "Comparison to user account fields" section on the Profile2 module page, if all of your users have the same fields, having an extra "Your profile" section rather than just your account doesn't really improve the UX. Entity Registration may help you here, just attached to a content type.